# How to make part of the code to be processed every 5 sec

Tags: c#, events, timer, gps, handler

I have a function that has event handler. It is reading gps position and everytime position is read I put data in the database, problem is that I have like 3 inputs for one sec.

How can I make some part of code to be proceeded every 5 sec for example?

I have tried to do timer_tick, but I don't know how to do it because this is function with event handler.

Here is my function:

```
private void GPS_PositionReceived(string Lat, string Lon)
{
    arrLon = Lon.Split(new char[] { '°', '"' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    dblLon = double.Parse(arrLon[0]) + double.Parse(arrLon[1], new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo()) / 60;
    deciLon = arrLon[2] == "E" ? dblLon : -dblLon;
    arrLat = Lat.Split(new char[] { '°', '"' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    dblLat = double.Parse(arrLat[0]) + double.Parse(arrLat[1], new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo()) / 60;
    deciLat = arrLat[2] == "N" ? dblLat : -dblLat;

                ...  //code
}
```

I want this part of the code to be used every 5 sec.

Oh yes and this is the event handler:

```
GPS.PositionReceived += new NmeaInterpreter.PositionReceivedEventHandler(GPS_PositionReceived);
```

Comment: I don't understand well the flow of your code. The GPS_PositionReceived event is called by? every? and what part of that code should be executed every 5 seconds?

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to limit the event handler to only being called a maximum of once per 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to say is that your method is being called 3 times a second, and in reality you only want it to be called every 5 seconds? Correct.

If so, store a

```
DateTime lastDBUpdate
```

variable, and everytime you write to the database, update this timestamp.

Then you can use a check like

```
if(DateTime.Now.Subtract(lastDBUpdate).TotalSeconds < 5) { return; }
```

As the first line of your method.

```
// Timestamp of last update time
// Default to very old timestamp on init so it always runs once straight away
private DateTime lastDBUpdate = DateTime.MinValue;

private void GPS_PositionReceived(string Lat, string Lon)
{
    // Throttle this method
    if(DateTime.Now.Subtract(lastDBUpdate).TotalSeconds < 5) return;

    // your existing code

    // Update the timestamp 
    lastDBUpdate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply by using a Timer, [Check This](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer)

Comment: I'm not convinced this is what the OP is asking for, please see @Dave Bish or my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could always have a static/class-level variable that indicated the last time the GPS position was persisted.

```
Public DateTime LastGPSInsert {get; set;}

...

if((DateTime.Now - LastGPSInsert).TotalSeconds > 5)
{
    //Do Insert
    LastGPSInsert = DateTime.Now;
}
//Skip insert
```

Comment: Good answer, but why would you want to make this a public property? A private field is more secure *and* slightly faster.